# fullpage.js normalScrollElements not scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using `fullPage.js` on my site and for some reason, the `normalScrollElements` is not working as I expect it to. I have 5 sections on my site and I need to have normal scrolling for `section2` which is `Showroom`. I used the normalScrollElements on that section and now the problem is that I cannot scroll down to the other sections(`Contact`, `About`). I don't know what code to put here, since it's basically `normalScrollElements`.

Here's a link to my site:
http://sabirmb.com/Parallax

Could anyone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been fixed. Basically the only thing that I had to add was `scrollOverflow:true` as explained in the documentation.

For future reference, if you have a section that has more content inside than the screen viewport, you should use `scrollOverflow:true` and this will allow for the content to scroll in that viewport.